# Json.NET deserialization on DateTime - not the right time(-6 hour)

Tags: c#, json, datetime, deserialization, converters

My application is from the client and server. Client and server exchange json data. Time zones on the same client and server (+4).This data class

```
public class MyData()
{
    public DateTime Start {get;set;}
}
```

On the server, I select data from the database MS SQL and give the client. When I deserialized on the client data field Start has  offset -6 hours. How can I get the correct time? Can I get the correct time on the client using JsonSerializerSettings? I tried

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat, 
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset, 
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
};
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(content,  jsonSerializerSettings);
```

but it gives the offset of +3. I need offset +6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serialization convert datetime to UTC. On deserialziation you need to convert it to [local time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx):

try something like this:

```
var dateWithLocalTimeZone = myDate.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: I try it, but it gives the offset of +3. I need offset +6.
Start (on server) - 13.00. Start (on client) - 7.00. Start.ToLocalTime() - 10.00

Comment: SOOOOO sooooo sooo awesome!  I couldn't find this answer anywhere, and this so easy and hidden. Thanks for pointing it out! :)